# How to fill a pgfgantt bar with a color gradient which fades from the center of the bar?

Tags: color, pgfgantt, fill, gradient

I'm trying to figure out how to fill a pgfgantt bar with a horizontal color gradient which fades from the center outwards. Unfortunately i'm having no luck!

I was wondering whether anyone knew how to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\definecolor{calendar_col}{RGB}{237,247,224}
\definecolor{color_a}{RGB}{140,102,25}
\definecolor{color_b}{RGB}{236,234,188}
\definecolor{color_c}{RGB}{98,113,140}


\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid,
                   inline,
                   title/.append style = {draw = black, fill = calendar_col},
                   group/.append style = {draw = black, shape=ganttgroup, inner sep=0pt, fill = black},
                   group left shift = 0,
                   group right shift = 0,
                   group height = 0.05,
                   group peaks tip position = 0,
                   group peaks width = 0.2,
                   group peaks height = 0.2,
                   y unit chart = 0.6cm,
                   bar height = 0.7, 
                   bar top shift = -0.2,
                   canvas/.style = {fill = calendar_col},
                   expand chart = \textwidth,
                   time slot format= isodate-yearmonth,
                   time slot unit = month]{2021-01}{2021-12}  
                   
\gantttitlecalendar{month = shortname} \\

\ganttgroup[group inline label node/.style={above=-5pt, font=\bfseries\color{black}}]{Year 1}{2021-06}{2021-06} \\
\ganttbar[bar/.append style = {fill = color_a}]{A}{2021-06}{2021-06} \\

\ganttgroup[group inline label node/.style={above=-5pt, font=\bfseries\color{black}}]{Year 2}{2021-03}{2021-03} \\

\ganttbar[bar/.append style = {fill = color_b}]{B}{2021-03}{2021-03} \\

\ganttgroup[group inline label node/.style={above=-5pt, font=\bfseries\color{black}}]{Year 3}{2021-01}{2021-09} \\
\ganttbar[bar/.append style = {fill = color_c}]{C}{2021-01}{2021-09}

\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Above is a minimal reproducible example for the type of chart i am producing. Ideally I would be able to define an RGB color, and fade that color to transparency towards the left and right hand sides of the bar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!